# How to dynamically create new row after an x number of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have JSON data that I want to add to a `table` dynamically. I have been able to do just that, but I want a situation whereby after the fourth column, a new row and column is automatically created and the remaining JSON data is filled in the newly created column. I have no idea how to perform this task.

Here is my code; the JSON data is from a database

```js
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var p = data[i];
  var occupied = p.occupied;

  $("#room").append('<td>\n\
   <div class="card cd" style="width: 15rem;">\n\
<img class="card-img-top" src="../images/Executive_Suite.jpg" alt="HOTEL D RIO">\n\
<div class="card-body r1" style="background-color: green">\n\
<h6 class="card-title name"><span>' + p.category + '</span><br/><span>' + p.position + '</span></h6> \n\
<p class="card-text price" style="color: #fff; font-size: 13px"><span>#' + p.unitprice + ' per 24hrs</span></p> \n\
<a type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm cbody cbody0" style="color: #fff;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Book Now</a>\n\
</div></div></td>');
}
```

Comment: What element is `#room`? That needs to be a `tr` for the HTML you're appending to be valid, as such you'll need to change the `append()` to add the HTML to a table instead to maintain validity.

Comment: What have you tried in relation to your requirement? It sounds like you just need to count how many columns you've created so far (maybe by a simple loop counter, or a separate counter variable which you increment manually) in the current row and when you get to 4, start a new row. The logic doesn't sound hard. The problem you may have is that `#room` will identify a single row of your table (assuming it is indeed a `<tr>` to start with...) - but of course a new row needs to be new, not an existing element.

Comment: You probably want to keep the `<table>` as an object and then create a new row object, and append the `<tds>` to it, and when you get to 4, add that row to the table, and loop round to start a new row. It's a bit unclear without seeing the related HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Occam's razor - just use a variable to keep track of where you are at. Probably my code does not create the desired HTML, but I trust you get the idea...?

```js
    rowcnt = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var out = '';
        var p = data[i];
        var occupied = p.occupied; 
        rowcnt++;
        if (rowcnt > 4){
            out += '</tr><tr>';
            rowcnt = 0;
        }else{
            out += '<td>\
                <div class="card cd" style="width: 15rem;">\
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="../images/Executive_Suite.jpg" alt="HOTEL D RIO">\
                    <div class="card-body r1" style="background-color: green">\
                        <h6 class="card-title name"><span>'+p.category+'</span><br/><span>'+p.position+'</span></h6>\
                        <p class="card-text price" style="color: #fff; font-size: 13px"><span>#'+p.unitprice+' per 24hrs</span></p>\
                        <a type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm cbody cbody0" style="color: #fff;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Book Now</a>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
            </td>';
        }
        $("#room").append(out);
    }
```

Comment: Should be much simpler using String literals